# AVL Tree rotations

Tags: data-structures, trees, databases, avl-trees

What size is the largest AVL tree for which an insertion could trigger a double rotation?

Comment: Can you give an example of when adding one node can cause several imbalances? Also, I'm not sure what relevance 'multiple imbalances' has to do with double rotations...

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Please clarify *in your question* whether *eventually be unbalanced* means change from *balanced* to *heights differ by one*, or change from *within limits* to *needs fixing*.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove its content.  When you post here, you are licensing your question to the community, for purposes of building up an archive of high-quality questions and answers (see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/editing).  If you no longer want an answer to your question, and it hasn't been answered yet, you can delete it using the 'delete' button under the question.

Comment: there is no delete button

Answer (score 1):

The insertion of a single element to an AVL-tree might *cause unbalance at several nodes* on the path from the root to the leaf where the new element was placed.

The tree can then be *restored by a rotation at a single node* on the path: the *lowest node with unbalance*. After that rotation the height of the subtree at that node is again the height it had before insertion, so all balance-factors above that point are again what they used to be before insertion.

The rotation that fixes the tree might be a single rotation or a double rotation depending on the position of the subtree that is deepest, as seen from the node where the rotation is performed.

In the example below we will rotate at node 4 to restore the balance caused by the insertion of node 6. (This will be a single rotation, to the left.)

[image: single element inserted causing unbalance at most positions along the insertion path]